# Deserializing yaml in C#

Tags: c#, deserialization, yamldotnet

I have a series of yaml files with a poorly implemented structure that I need to parse in C#. The schema resembles:

```
Root:
    KnownTypeA:
        VariableNameLevel3A:
            VariableNameLevel4A:
                KnownTypeAPropertyA:  Bar
                KnownTypeAPropertyB:  Bar
                KnownTypeAPropertyZ:  Bar    
    KnownTypeB:
        VariableNameLevel3B:
            VariableNameLevel4B:
                KnownTypeBPropertyA:  Baz
                KnownTypeBPropertyB:  Baz
                KnownTypeBPropertyZ:  Baz

    KnownTypeZ:
        VariableNameLevel3C:
            - Foo
            - Foo
            - Foo

SomePropertyA: Foo
SomePropertyA: Bar
SomePropertyA: Baz
```

Children of `Root` can be zero or more of known values, `KnownTypeA..Z`.
The next 2 levels of descendants are arbitrary values, `VariableNameLevel3A..Z` and `VariableNameLevel4A..Z`. The last level of key/value collections map to the model described by the parent in level 2, `KnownTypeA..Z`. The properties collections are not inclusive and generally miss one or more.

Finally, the first level may have other key/value collections beneath the known `Root` node of interest.

I looked at c# yaml implementations and it seems yamldotnet is the most maintained however it lacks documentation. Is manually parsing this mess the only alternative or does anyone know of an implementation that might yield some insight to an approach with models where the deserializer can apply the most appropriate model to the `VariableNameLevel4x` collections?

Comment: there is nuget package for that

Comment: Although YamlDotNet documentation is lacking, you can use this as reference: https://github.com/aaubry/YamlDotNet/wiki/Samples.LoadingAYamlStream

Comment: @Yarimi that was the doc I used to manually parse the file, however I was hoping for an approach similar to the object graph.